# What is a formal definition of "algebraic degree of accuracy" regarding numerical integration?

Tags: numerical-methods

I am given one example that deals with numeric integration. It is a classic example of determining coefficients $A_1,...A_n$ such that the given quadratic formula is valid for all algebraic polynomials of some degree. The next part of this problem asks to determine the "algebraic degree of accuracy".

**Question:** What is "algebraic degree of accuracy" regarding numerical integration? Could you show on an example (regarding this given problem) how to determine the algebraic degree of accuracy?

Comment: Is the problem from a book? If so, which one?

Comment: @quasi, No, it is not from a book?

Comment: Degree of accuracy could mean different things, depending on the context. That's why I asked if you're using a textbook. I could guess a meaning, but that would just be a guess.

Comment: Also, you say all polynomials of "some degree", but then you allude to the quadratic formula, which relates to polynomials of degree 2. What's up with that?

Comment: @quasi, It is not quadratic, it is quadrature formula. Could you tell what is your guess for the definition of algebraic degree of accuracy? I can't find any reference in any context - here, it is numerical integration.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to guess. Given that it's an assigned problem and there's no textbook, it should be in your class notes. Or simply ask your professor for a link or reference.

Comment: @quasi, Actually, I can't find any reference regarding that term.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136633/numerical-integration-the-degree-of-accuracy-of-a-quadrature

Comment: Try these:
$$$$
http://www3.nd.edu/~zxu2/acms40390F15/Lec-4.3.pdf
$$$$
http://www3.nd.edu/~zxu2/acms40390F15/Lec-4.4.pdf
$$$$
http://www3.nd.edu/~zxu2/acms40390F15/Lec-4.7.pdf
$$$$